# assigning names from a file to an index

Tags: python-3.x

I am making a top trumps game in python and I need some help with something.
I need to assign names from a txt file to an index but to an amount given by the user.

```
def game():
cards = input("How many cards do you want to play with? (answer must be greater than 4, less than 30 and even \n")
cards = int(cards)
if cards % 2 != 0:
    print("Error, answer must be even")
    print(cards % 2)
    menu()
if cards < 4 or cards > 30:
    print("Error, answer must be greater than 4 and less than 30")
    menu()
with open("dogs.txt","r") as f:
```

This is the code but I can't think of what to put after opening the file, if anyone can help me would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Simply try the `read()` or `readline()` function, for example:

```
f.readline()
```

Comment: but how would I assign them to an index and only as many as the user inputs.
e.g. User inputs 6, so 6 names are set to index